# Retrieve attribute code

Tags: magento

A very small thing that is driving me crazy :)

I am not able to retrieve the attribute code of the current attribute in the `/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml` template file.

Around (or at) line 36, when I change the

```
echo $_attribute->getLabel()
```

to

```
echo $_attribute->getAttributeId()
```

I get the correct attribute Id that is present in the `eav_attribute` table of the database.
But when I try

```
echo $_attribute->getAttributeCode()
```

I get an empty string whereas there is an `attribute_code` field in the `eav_attribute` table.

Can you please help me find the attribute code of my attribute ? Or, more generally : how to get the attribute code of an attribute from which we now the id ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No need to overload Magento base code in this case.
If you print_r($_attribute) you can see Attribute Code is deeper in array() and you can use it directly in you template file this way:

```
echo $_attribute->getProductAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
```

Answer (score 4):

just try

```
$_attribute_code = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load($_attribute->getAttributeId())->getAttributeCode();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * get attribute collection
 */
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_attribute');
/**
 * get attribute type
 */
$attribute->getAttributeType();
/**
 * get attribute Label
 */
$attribute->getFrontendLabel();
/**
 * get attribute default value
 */
$attribute->getDefaultValue();
/**
 * check if the attribute is visible
 */
$attribute->getIsVisible();
/**
 * check if the attribute is required
 */
$attribute->getIsRequired();
/**
 * get attribute value
 */
$attributeValue = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMyAttribute();
```

Here is detailed code and explanation about getting attribute name, code and value : http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-get-attribute-name-and-value/

Comment: Hey Mukesh, I've seen your post prior to posting by own answer :) So funny. But I didn't think that the last snippet would do the trick... So I took inspiration from it to make my own which, as you saw, needs to overload the main Collection.php file...
Anyway, you got the ticker!

Answer (score 0):

I just tried that code on my magento installation and it returns the correct attribute code. You can always try getting to the data directly:

```
echo $_attribute->attribute_code;
```

but I don't think this will help. Try `var_dump` or `print_r` on the `$_attribute` variable to see if the data is really missing.

Comment: Thanks man for answering Silvo !
But echo $_attribute->attribute_code didn't return nothing either and the print_r returned something that made me think that the attribute code is encapsulated into another array that I didn't find a way to point dynamically. Anyway, found a sooooo strange solution that I've posted below.

Answer (score 0):

So found a way which I'm sure is not the best way to do... or maybe Magento team didn't think that one may need to get the attribute code based on attribute id...

1- **Overload** app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Mysql4/Entity/Attribute/Collection.php

Add this method :

```
public function setIdFilter($id)
    {
        if (empty($id)) {
            return $this;
        }
        if (!is_array($id)) {
            $id = array($id);
        }
        $this->getSelect()->where('main_table.attribute_id IN(?)', $id);
        return $this;
    }
```

2- Now to retrieve the code of the attribute based on its id use :

```
$attributeCode = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
        ->setIdFilter(YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_ID) /* if using this into the configurable.phtml template file, you can use $_attribute->getAttributeId() for YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_ID */
        ->getFirstItem()
        ->getAttributeCode();
echo $attributeCode;
```

So unituitive but so working...

If someone's got a better way to do it, I'd be happy to change my "answer ticker"!

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but since this came up in Google I'd like to provide an answer.

I was able to get attribute codes with this php:

```
$productAttributeOptions = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)
  ->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($_product);
print_r($productAttributeOptions);
```

PS, Magento is so damn frustrating.